# How to get the min x, max x, min y and max y of a certain figure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to design a function, which can add text in the right corner of the figure according to user's input parameter ('UpperLeft', 'UpperRight', 'LowerLeft', 'LowerRight'). I implement it in the following way: If I want to add text in the upper left corner, I firstly get the min x and max y of the axis in the figure, then use `text(min_x, max_y, 'text')` to draw it . But I don't know what function can get the min x and max y. And if there any other way to implement the function I want?

Comment: Please do not add the answer to the question. If it is different from the answers already given, you can post it as an answer below.

Comment: I think Horizontal and VerticalAlignment flags in `text` is probably what you are looking for. The question, though, asks for getting the bounds of a figure as values (hence my answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 3*sin(linspace(0,10,100));
figure
plot(x)
xl = xlim
yl = ylim
% upper left (ish), you'll want to position the text a little down and to
% the right depending on the dimensions of the plot
text(xl(1), yl(2), 'text')
```

[image]

Comment: You can set the `'VerticalAlignment'` to `'Top'` to avoid having to manually nudge the text down or it clashing with the plot bounds